# How to calculate the profit of sales orders for a given time if the cost if variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below tables in database, I need to calculate the revenue(sum of sell price of all orders ), the cost (sum of all costs of all sold products) and the profit (the revenue minus the cost). However the cost is variable. 
The cost of an item may be changed with time.

Example: I bought 10 items of item X for $ 5
3 items were sold. Then I bought 3 items of X for $ 4

I tried getting the average cost of item x and then use it to calculate the profit, but it is not a good approach.

How can I know the cost of item x for each sales order? Is there a way to do that?

I don't want a code . I just need an idea for solving this issue!

- sales_order

  id

  grand_total (sum of sell_price of its items)

  order_status (pending/complete)

  delivery_date (date)
- sales_order_item

  id

  sales_order_id

  product_id (unique)

  quantity (ordered quantity)

  sell_price (sell price for single item)
- purchase_order

  id

  created_at

  status (pending / approved)
- purchase_order_items

  id

  purchase_order_id

  product_id

  cost  (cost of each item)

Comment: its like a Homework .. ok what have you tried ?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I don't want you to write a code. I just need the idea. Is it doable or not!

Comment: Nearly everything is doable with enough time and effort ;-)

Comment: I tried getting the average price = sum(quantity * cost) / sum(quantity). But since cost is variable, I can't get fixed number in reports.

Also I tried getting the cost from the nearest purchase order date. But it was not accurate.

Comment: This looks like a mathematical and logical question more than programming/coding which SO is here for.

Answer (score 1):

Well if I understand correctly, you can fetch purchase_order_items and sales_order_item (with product_id) and for each product_id income is sell_price * quantity and cost is cost * quantity.

**UPDATE:** Using inner join.

**UPDATE:** If you are not keeping the actual variable that effects the cost then the only solution is machine learning or statistics (probability theory).

Comment: Then you can only do it by keeping costs with time stamps OR you can go more crazy normal/Gaussian distribution (probability theory).

Comment: If you are not keeping the actual variable that effects the cost then the only solution is machine learning or statistics.

Comment: An example would be something like K Means Algorithm. (Entering the A.I. field.)